# ExtJS window dynamically add GridPanel items and show it

Tags: extjs

I want to show only one GridPanel,which I dynamically add by switch click button event, in window.

```
var event_menu = new Ext.menu.Menu( {
    id : "event_menu",
    items : [ {
        text : 'record1',
        handler : function() {
            win.add(item_list_panel);//dynamica add GridPanel to show server data
            win.doLayout();
            item_list_store.load();
        }
    }, {
        text : 'record2',
        handler : function() {
                           win.remove(item_list_panel);//I want to remove it inorder to show the item_list_panel2 and only show one panel.
            win.add(item_list_panel2);
            win.doLayout();
            item_list_store.load();
        }
    } ]
});
```

and this menu belong to my window tbar.
when I click record win will show `item_list_panel` and I want to when I click `record2` the `item_list_panel2` will show in win and `item_list_panel` will hide.
If I `win.remove(item_list_panel)` will have an error :

```
c.getPositionEl().dom is undefined
```

How can I do it,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can barely understand your question, but if I understand correctly you can do it several ways.

you can destroy the component directly

```
item_list_panel.destroy()
```

you can go through your items and select it by id

```
win.items.item('item_id').destroy()
```

There are also ways to remove it without completely destroying it, depends what you want to do

Comment: if this helped you, help me out and make it the answer :)

Comment: Thanks, It's worked for my problem with panel as well as button component.